# Permissions dialog in Facebook iOS native app

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 to log-in into my app, the following method is invoked:

FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions

If native iOS login is not enabled and facebook iOS app is installed, the login process will get redirected to the facebook app. The problem is that every single time 'FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions'is invoked, the facebook app presents the permission dialog to the user, even when the user already authorized the FB app.

The permission list is empty (nil). This problem does not happen if native ios or safari are used to log -in.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the user has successfully logged in by checking for an access token [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession/#accessToken)

Also, you can make sure you aren't popping up a GUI from each call by setting allowLoginUI to false.

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI;
```

I've not done any iOS FB stuff myself, but that's what I got from reading the docs.

Also, there seems to be a somewhat related question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458597/openactivesessionwithreadpermissions-does-not-log-in-automatically).